# Jquery - How to hide h2 before table and text after table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on my website and I don't know how to hide h2 tag before table and text after table. Can you help me ? Thank you very much for help.

HTML:

```
<h2>
  <a class="h2 dark" href="/be/ae/3_controls-training.html" name="3">Controls Training</a>
</h2>
<table class="training" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display: none;">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th style="text-align: left;">Training</th>
     <th style="text-align: left;">Start</th>
     <th style="text-align: left;">End</th>
     <th style="text-align: left;">Location</th>
     <th style="text-align: right;">Price*</th>
     <th> </th>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
)* EUR excl. BTW
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // this is code for hiding my table if td is not inside
    $('.training').each(function(){
       if ($(this).find('td').length == 0){
        $(this).closest('h2').hide(); // I try to hide h2 before table without success
        $(this).hide(); // this works fine
        // I don't know how to hide text after table
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just remove it from your html code?

Comment: @Stefan  I don't know what you mean ?

Comment: You want to hide the h2 tag but what about removing it from your html code?

Comment: @Stefan this is just part of my code: There are several tables with data inside. I need hide only empty tables with h2 before and text after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the previous element in the DOM you can use jQuery .prev() http://api.jquery.com/prev/

```
$(this).prev().hide();
```

You can't select the text as it is not a DOM element. Wrap it in p tags and then you can use .next() http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
$(this).next().hide();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sfctbnkz/

Comment: this will work as long as your wrap it, which you should. it really depends on if the h2 and text are always going to fall directly before and after

Comment: That's why I said "Wrap it in p tags and then you can use .next()" ;)

Comment: @Tim He could very well remove it If he can wrap it.. right.. Not sure if he has access to the markup.. but that is an assumption.

Comment: @Vega True, hopefully that is not the case for the OP

Comment: Thank you, I wraped text after table and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy if you can wrap that `#text` with a `span` or a `div`. Then you can use `.prev` and `.next` to select the elements before and after the table.

In case, If you don't have access to the markup.. then the only way is to get the contents and look for the text and delete it..

See below demo.. It is going to display nothing.. since the output of your OP is to remove/hide everything. :)

**Note:** The below code removes the next text node after the table.. so test it properly and change it as required.

```js
$('.training').each(function() {
  $(this).prev('h2').remove(); //remove or hide h2
  var tableSiblings = $(this).parent().contents();
  var deleteNext = false;
  $.each(tableSiblings, function(i, content) {
    if (deleteNext) {
      $(this).remove();
      deleteNext = false;
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('training')) {
      deleteNext = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  <a class="h2 dark" href="/be/ae/3_controls-training.html" name="3">Controls Training</a>
</h2>
<table class="training" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display: none;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: left;">Training</th>
      <th style="text-align: left;">Start</th>
      <th style="text-align: left;">End</th>
      <th style="text-align: left;">Location</th>
      <th style="text-align: right;">Price*</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
)* EUR excl. BTW
```

Comment: WOW, thank you very much for your time and this code. I wraped my text between div tags and works fine with .prev() and .next() function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.training').closest( 'h2' ).hide(); // will hide closest h2 tag, but could be after
$('.training').next().hide(); // will hide element directly after .training
```

You should try adding classes specific to what you're trying to do, instead of relying on dom elements